# Difference between %d and %p printf format string directives in c language?

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion

I want to get a detailed explanation on the difference between using `%d` and `%p` type for `printing pointer`.

Also 
Why does `%p` return hexadecimal?
What are the cases when `%d` and `%p` return different values?
Does datatype only represent the way the user wants the output or it has something to do with the memory locations too?

Comment: Wrong terminology: `%p` or `%d` are not datatypes (like `int` or `void*`), but `printf` format string directives.

Comment: BTW, if compiling with `gcc -Wall -g` you'll probably get a warning when misusing these format string directives (at least when the format string is a literal constant argument to `printf`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the program to be well-defined, the format specifier must match the type of the argument. Therefore you can use `%p` but not `%d` to print out pointers. (The latter might happen to work on some architectures but is technically [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).)

The primary reason you can't freely interchange `%d` and `%p` is that `ints` and pointers don't have to have the same size.

The format in which pointers are printed out is architecture-specific (pointers can have different size or indeed different [structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model#Memory_segmentation)). It is, however, common to transcribe memory addresses in hexadecimal, so this is what `%p` usually does.

Answer (score 1):

Those conversions are highly architecture dependent.  One of the most clear distinctions are with the real mode 8086 where `int` is 16 bits and a (large model) pointer is 32 bits but has a segment and offset which are always written as segment:offset.

```
%d    takes 16 bits and displays it as a signed value  123
%p    takes a pointer and display it in address format    0fef:0004
```

Since `%p` was introduced relatively recently I don't know of any implementations but a PDP-11 library ought to implement it by display the 16-bit address in octal.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer of variable in C has value just like other type of variable such as the int、char and so on. The %p format string in  the printf function just indicates that the type of parameter "i" is pointer to the printf instead of int. Thus printf outputs the Hex value of parameter i because printf seem the parameter i as a pointer type. No matter what the type of variable i is, the value is same----10 or 0xa. The difference between the types of i---int or pointer ----is the different ways to use  in C. if type of i is regarded as pointer, you can visit the memory specified by value of pointer i or other operations the pointer type  supports. If type of i is int, we can do some operations such as addition or subtraction rather than visiting the memory by using value of i, because the grammar of C do't allow you to do that(just warning). if you know what you want to do, you can do that.